# How to access items in a css grid by X Y via JS?

Tags: javascript, css, css-grid

I am using a responsive [CSS grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) and I am looking for a way to access the elements through x, y indices.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  padding: 10px;
  background: DeepSkyBlue;
  grid-gap: 1px;
}

.grid-item {
  text-align: center;
  background: LightCyan;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item">9</div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to access the columns/rows of the CSS grid via vanilla JS like:

```
document.getElementOfCssGrid(2, 3)
```

Comment: I don't think JS has any knowledge of CSS grids.

Comment: If that is really the case, I would accept that as an answer

Comment: You would most likely do this via the DOM, rather than CSS.

Comment: I would if I had proof, but I do not

Comment: @evolutionxbox Fair enough :-)

Comment: I'm confused how this question _can_ include debugging details. Maybe add some HTML and CSS?

Comment: Will do, great idea

Comment: This won't be purely possible unless your JS knows or can determine the grid properties. Then you also have to take into account any media queries that might change the grid layout based on viewport size. To be honest, this is probably too broad a question for StackOverflow at this stage.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the specification what the question lacks. Btw, also thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 3):

You have a fixed number of columns so all you need is a basic math formula:

```js
/* x for the row and y for the column  */
function getElementOfCssGrid(x, y) {
  let n = 3*(x - 1) + y;
  return document.querySelector('.grid-item:nth-child('+n+')');
}

console.log(getElementOfCssGrid(2,3).innerHTML)
console.log(getElementOfCssGrid(1,3).innerHTML)
console.log(getElementOfCssGrid(1,1).innerHTML)
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  padding: 10px;
  background: DeepSkyBlue;
  grid-gap: 1px;
}

.grid-item {
  text-align: center;
  background: LightCyan;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item">9</div>
</div>
```

If the number of columns is not known you can easily calculate it:

```js
/* x for the row and y for the column  */
function getElementOfCssGrid(x, y) {
  let gridComputedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.grid-container'));
  let col = gridComputedStyle.getPropertyValue("grid-template-columns").split(" ").length;

  let n = col*(x - 1) + y;
  return document.querySelector('.grid-item:nth-child('+n+')');
}

console.log(getElementOfCssGrid(2,3).innerHTML)
console.log(getElementOfCssGrid(1,3).innerHTML)
console.log(getElementOfCssGrid(1,1).innerHTML)
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  padding: 10px;
  background: DeepSkyBlue;
  grid-gap: 1px;
}

.grid-item {
  text-align: center;
  background: LightCyan;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item">9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, that's smart. I didn't think of `.grid-item:nth-child`. Thanks a lot!